# Bedeutung von „Ich mach dich nicht null an“

Tags: meaning-in-context

Ich habe eine Nachricht von einem Mädchen bekommen, das ich vor kurzem getroffen habe, und wir haben uns über Instagram ausgetauscht. Dann hat sie mir das geschickt:

> ich mach dich nicht null an.

Was meint sie damit?

Comment: Was that on a mobile, maybe with autocorrect in play?

Comment: Hast Du ihr zuvor geschrieben "Du machst mich Null an"?

Comment: Die einzig richtige Reaktion in so einem Fall ist, jeglichen Kontakt sofort abzubrechen - wer sich so ausdrückt, der frißt auch kleine Kinder.

Answer (score 5):

Das kann man nur mit mehr Kontext entscheiden.

- jemanden anmachen — jemanden beschimpfen
- jemanden anmachen — jemanden sexuell erregen

Dazu kommt noch, das *nicht null* eine doppelte Negation ist und die kann auch auf verschiedene Weise verstanden werden:

- nicht null — etwas
- nicht null — sehr
- nicht null — gar nicht

Sag doch einfach die Wahrheit, dass sie sich klarer ausdrücken muss.